# Is there a technical reason why devs use a C function in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c

Is there a technical reason why some developers use C style function calls, commonly for utility type functions.

Is it to be compilable on non objective-c type situations, or is there some other advantage such as speed?

Comment: Flagging to close as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @MDXF I don't think the question in itself is opinion based, however it may lead to opinion based answers. I've edited the question to style it more towards fact based, technical answers rather than opinion.

Comment: @JamesKrawczyk If a question begins with "Why do some developers", it's clearly opinion-based.

Comment: @MDXF Right, which is why I edited the question to ask for a non-opinion based answer. The question itself isn't inherently bad for StackOverflow, it was just worded poorly. It's perfectly fine to ask a question here that the answer may be "There is no technical reason, it's personal style.". What isn't okay is explaining that personal style as an answer.

Comment: @JamesKrawczyk If the answer *could be* an explanation of personal style, the question is off-topic. And as your edit hasn't yet been approved, I wouldn't speak so soon...

Comment: Oh wow! That's a shame, I'm sure its valuable knowledge. Don't recall SO being so rigid.

Comment: Flagged to reopen. I think there are purely technical answers to this question that are totally valid. Compatibility, speed (in some rare cases), obfuscation in output binary, lack of participation in the runtime (for some amount of security), etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few technical reasons for writing C-style code in an Objective-C project:

1. As you mention, **compatibility**: if the code in question is not Objective-C-specific, factoring it out into a C function allows it to be used in C projects as well (and C++ projects, as long as it is valid C++). For shared libraries, this is useful.
2. Occasionally, **speed**: the compiler can introspect into some C functions and [inline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) them, allowing for enhanced optimization of the code. Objective-C method calls, on the other hand, *cannot* be inlined (they are completely dynamic — methods can be overridden and replaced at runtime, so it is not valid to replace an Objective-C method call with a static dispatch at compile time), and so incur the overhead of an `objc_msgSend` on every call.

   In the vast majority of cases, converting an Objective-C method to a C function will ***not*** net a substantial speed increase (so don't go replacing method calls with C functions unless it makes sense for the code), but occasionally, in tight loops where a function call may be inlined and vectorized, you could potentially see a speed benefit.
3. In some applications, the **obfuscation** may help. When an Objective-C application is compiled, all class names and selector names are compiled into the app binary itself. You can see the results of this by running `/usr/bin/strings` on a binary — all method names will be present.

   C function names, however, are stripped from the app binary as long as you don't leave the debug info flag on (`-g`, off for release builds), and are this not present in the binary.

   Depending on what you are doing and may want to protect against, this may make it harder for someone to inspect your app binary to look for things to exploit, and allows more intricate obfuscation of the code. Potentially useful for *somewhat* protecting things like serial number validation and the like, but keep in mind that unless your app is [code signed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_signing), anyone who gets a hold of the binary may modify it to do whatever they want. (This might just make it more difficult.)
4. Along the same vein, C functions are not present in the **runtime**, making them much more difficult to call dynamically (potentially in a malicious way). Because of the dynamism of Objective-C, all classes, methods, instance variables, etc. can be looked up, introspected, and modified at runtime. For most apps, this is not a concern, but if you have an application with a plugin architecture, this is something to be aware of — depending on how you load plugins or bundles into your process, code you don't own may have access to your entire application at runtime.

   Depending on what you're doing, this may expose data that you don't want to have exposed. C functions, on the other hand, are not exposed in this way, and it would take a bit more work to call into those. Certainly not impossible (I mean, you're loading remote code into your app), but a bit more difficult. This is more **security by obscurity** than actual security (as opposed to, say, running the plugin in its own process, separated from yours).

In all, for the vast majority of apps, there is no benefit to writing C-style code beyond stylistic reasons. Familiarity and code style can go a long way, but the majority of the apps won't see an appreciable benefit to writing C-style code. The "security" benefits are more of a nuisance to someone determined to break your app than anything else, and any speed improvements are likely dwarfed by things like disk access and network calls.